# .User is a not managed type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am getting an error when I am running my application

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:583) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:233) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:182) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:165) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:325) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
```

Application structure

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxW9J.png)

pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

RestartApplication.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class RestartApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestartApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

MvcConfig

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class RestartApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestartApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, active from user where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username, ur.roles from usr u inner join userRole ur on u.id = ur.userId where u.username=?");
    }
}
```

AuthenticationController (it displays welcome page)

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class AuthenticationController {
    @GetMapping("/")
        public String authentication(Map<String, Object> model) {
            return "authentication";
        }
}
```

BlogController

```
import com.Vova.Restart.Models.Post;
import com.Vova.Restart.repo.PostRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;

@Controller
public class BlogController {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @GetMapping("/blog")
    public String blogMain(Model model) {
        Iterable<Post> posts = postRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("posts", posts);
        return "blog";
    }

    @GetMapping("/blog/add")
    public String blogAdd(Model model) {
        return "blogAdd";
    }

    @PostMapping("/blog/add")
    public String blogPostAdd(@RequestParam String title, @RequestParam String anons, @RequestParam String full_text, Model model) {
        Post post = new Post(title, anons, full_text);
        postRepository.save(post);
        return "redirect:/blog";
    }

    @GetMapping("/blog/{id}")
    public String blogDetails(@PathVariable(value = "id") long postId, Model model) {
        if(!postRepository.existsById(postId)) {
            return "redirect:/blog";
        }

        Optional<Post> post = postRepository.findById(postId);
        ArrayList<Post> res = new ArrayList<>();
        post.ifPresent(res::add);
        model.addAttribute("post", res);
        return "blogDetails";
    }

    @GetMapping("/blog/{id}/edit")
    public String blogEdit(@PathVariable(value = "id") long postId, Model model) {
        if(!postRepository.existsById(postId)) {
            return "redirect:/blog";
        }

        Optional<Post> post = postRepository.findById(postId);
        ArrayList<Post> res = new ArrayList<>();
        post.ifPresent(res::add);
        model.addAttribute("post", res);
        return "blogEdit";
    }

    @PostMapping("/blog/{id}/edit")
    public String blogPostUpdate(@PathVariable(value = "id") long postId, @RequestParam String title, @RequestParam String anons, @RequestParam String full_text, Model model) {
        Post post = postRepository.findById(postId).orElseThrow();
        post.setTitle(title);
        post.setAnons(anons);
        post.setFull_text(full_text);
        postRepository.save(post);

        return "redirect:/blog";
    }

    @PostMapping("/blog/{id}/remove")
    public String blogPostDelete(@PathVariable(value = "id") long postId, Model model) {
        Post post = postRepository.findById(postId).orElseThrow();
        postRepository.delete(post);

        return "redirect:/blog";
    }
}
```

MainController

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;


@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Главная страница");
        return "home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/about")
    public String about(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "О нас");
        return "about";
    }
}
```

RegistrationController

```
import com.Vova.Restart.Models.Role;
import com.Vova.Restart.repo.UserRepo;
import com.Vova.Restart.Models.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class RegistrationController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;


    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registration() {
        return "registration";
    }

    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String addUser (User user, Map<String, Object> model) {
        User userFromDb = userRepo.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

        if (userFromDb != null) {
            model.put("message", "User exists!");
            return "registration";
        }

        user.setActive(true);
        user.setRole(Collections.singleton(Role.USER));

        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

Post

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title, anons, full_text;
    private int views;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAnons() {
        return anons;
    }

    public void setAnons(String anons) {
        this.anons = anons;
    }

    public String getFull_text() {
        return full_text;
    }

    public void setFull_text(String full_text) {
        this.full_text = full_text;
    }

    public int getViews() {
        return views;
    }

    public void setViews(int views) {
        this.views = views;
    }

    public Post() {
    }

    public Post(String title, String anons, String full_text) {
        this.title = title;
        this.anons = anons;
        this.full_text = full_text;
    }
}
```

Role

```
public enum Role {
    USER;
}
```

User

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;


@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username, password;
    private boolean active;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "userRole", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public void setRole(Set<Object> singleton) {

    }
}
```

PostRepository

```
import com.Vova.Restart.Models.Post;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;


public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post, Long> {
}
```

UserRepo

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;


public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    com.Vova.Restart.Models.User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

I tried to fix it using @EnableJpaRepositories and @EntityScan but this does not help.
In my MySQL all tables was added automaticly.
My Java version is 17

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Import is wrong. Please import your User class entity instead of spring's user class.

```
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
```

Note: Always follow coding standards. The package should be all lowercase to prevent unwanted errors.

Comment: But if you change it, then an error occurs in the following lines
`User userFromDb = userRepo.findByUsername(user.getUsername());`
`user.setActive(true);`
`user.setRole(Collections.singleton(Role.USER));`
Maybe there is some way to replace it.

Comment: Your import is wrong and that is why you are getting the IllegalArgumentException you reference in your question. If you are getting a different error after correcting the import then consider posting a new question *after* checking for any existing questions that may address the issue